# JQuery replace href value for all with same ID

Tags: jquery

I want to replace `href` value for all

```
<a id ="replaceValue" href=""> test1 </a>

<a id ="replaceValue" href="">test2 </a>
```

`<a>` tag Id is same for both. I want to change the value of both.

```
$("#replaceValue").attr("href", "test.html");
```

This function is working well but it only change for first `<a>` tag. Please help me changing both with same function.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: don't have these problems when html is valid with unique ID..change ID to class

Comment: Please venerate this question. It's an honest question with the right idea in mind but the wrong intention / implementation and should serve as a warning beacon should this ever be found in the future. Pay it forward basically.

Answer (score 4):

You should uses classes instead of ID's as ID's are meant to be unique. This should do what you need using classes:

```
$('a.replaceValue').attr('href','NEW URL HERE');
```

Answer (score 2):

IDs are unique identifiers. Use name or alt or class for cumulative operations

Answer (score 1):

```
< a class ="replaceValue" href="" > test1 < /a>

< a class ="replaceValue" href="" >test2 < /a>
```

Change ID's to class as per specs ID's must be unique in any page

```
$(".replaceValue").attr("href", "test.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control over the markup, you *can* select all of these by treating `id` as a generic attribute, and using a jQuery attribute selector.

***BUT***, if you have control over the html, **don't do this**, change the IDs to classes.

```
$('a[id=replaceValue]').attr('href', 'http://myurl.com');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ySzCL/1/

Comment: Why did you have to post this D: Now @Drozzy's doing it all wrong!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: I know...  I have contributed to the decline of society.  I should have mentioned that every time you do this, a kitten dies.

Comment: I up-voted (almost) everyone else as penance.  Perhaps I will just delete this answer to prevent others from finding it...

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#replaceValue').each(function() {
$(this).attr('href','url');
})
```

Comment: Calling `each` on an ID selector doesn't make sense, as an ID is a single item by definition.  Internally, javascript will only return the first item with that ID, even if multiples exist in the DOM.